# finding the error

Tags: grammar, phrases, errors

Her aunt didn't (a)/ give me (b)/ a minute of peace (c)/No error (d).

This question  of finding error came into my semester exam, the answer is in part (c) but i didn't get any error in it, Kindly tell me whether this phrase is correct "a minute of peace".

Comment: It should likely read "peace for one minute". Although (c) is certainly used idiomatically over here in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

I fail to see any error. Other versions include, "a minute's peace," "a moment's peace" and "a moment of peace." Don't give your teacher a minute of peace until you get an explanation.

(This probably doesn't qualify as an answer, but I'm not yet allowed to post comments.)

Comment: It's impossible to know what the test creator was thinking, but an [Ngram comparison](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+minute%27s+peace%2Ca+minute+of+peace&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20minute%20%27s%20peace%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20minute%20of%20peace%3B%2Cc0) of "a minute's peace" versus "a minute of peace" suggests that the former is considerably more common. But relative idiomatic popularity doesn't resolve into an error/no error dichotomy, so I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: Looks like an answer to me, mine would've been very similar if I'd seen the question earlier but the point @SvenYargs  makes about frequency of use is also valid. Perhaps that is why the OP's tutor thinks that it is wrong.